# scrape top 100 job results from indeed using BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python web scraping and i would like to scrape top 100 job results from indeed and im only able to scrape first page results i.e top 10. I'm using BeautifulSoup framework. This is my code and can anyone help me with this problem?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

URL = "https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read(), 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard'})

for x in results:
company = x.find('span', attrs={"class":"company"})
print 'company:', company.text.strip()

job = x.find('a', attrs={'data-tn-element': "jobTitle"})
print 'job:', job.text.strip()
```

Comment: I have added an answer can you please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in batches of 10 changing the start value in the url. You can loop incrementing and adding the add variable

https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka&start=0

https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru,+Karnataka&start=1

E.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
results = []
url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru,+Karnataka&start={}'
with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(5):
        res = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        titles = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('[data-tn-element=jobTitle]')]
        companies = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.company')]
        data = list(zip(titles, companies))
        results.append(data)
newList = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(newList)
df.to_json(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.json')
```

Comment: can you store it in a json file?

Comment: The answer is probably yes. I would appear the lists and convert to df and see if pandas has a Json method

Comment: I jus tried. But in console results look quite embarrassing. Can you store them in json format.

Comment: If there is anything that needs improving please let me know. You need to amend the path.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can you give me json format like `{"Company":"nameOfCompany", "title":"jobtitle"}`

Comment: sure. Vote this question if you think it's useful to other developers.

Comment: Apologies. I should have done that in the first place. Just was very early in the morning!

Comment: How i can add multiprocessing/multithreading to it and when to parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.It will navigate to next page upto 10 pages.If you want to take more than 100 records just replace `while page_num<100:` to `while True:`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka"
company_name = []
job_title = []
page_num = 10
session = requests.Session()
while True:
    pageTree = session.get(page, headers=headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    jobs= pageSoup.find_all("a", {"data-tn-element": "jobTitle"})
    Companys = pageSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "company"})
    for Company, job in zip(Companys, jobs):
        companyname=Company.text
        company_name.append(companyname.replace("\n",""))
        job_title.append(job.text)
    if pageSoup.find("span", text=re.compile("Next")):
        page = "https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka&start={}".format(page_num)
        page_num +=10
    else:
        break

print(company_name)
print(job_title)
df = pd.DataFrame({"company_name":company_name,"job_title":job_title})
print(df.head(1000))
```

Comment: Yeah. It's working. Can you please explain me the logic.

Comment: You have to use requests.session to traverse multiple pages.if you click on next page you will see the counter increases 10 per page.In my code I have added counter 10.

Comment: yeah. That's really helped me. do you know how to store it in a css in an order.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer.You use pandas to store in order.I dont know about css.

Comment: I have updated my answer with pandas.please check and accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: I will. It really helped me. upvote the question if you think it's helpful to other developers.

Comment: can i improve to 1000 results if i want to?

Comment: Yes you can improve to 1000 as well.

Comment: page_num = 100?

Comment: try while True:

Comment: Updated the answer.Just try

Comment: I have updated the code.Have tried to run the code?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({"company_name":company_name,"job_title":job_title})
for urls in page:
 json_file2 = open('fin.json','w')
 json.dump(df,json_file2)
 json_file2.close()` This is what i tried to create json file. But in last getting an error like this `[144 rows x 2 columns] is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you include your code inside a range loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import urllib2

URL = "https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka&start="

for i in range(0 , 100 , 10):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL+str(i)).read(), 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard'})
    for x in results:
        company = x.find('span', attrs={"class":"company"})
        print 'company:', company.text.strip()

        job = x.find('a', attrs={'data-tn-element': "jobTitle"})
        print 'job:', job.text.strip()
```

Comment: What error do you have? I admit I tested this using `requests` package and not `urllib2`

Comment: `Temporary failure in name resolution` this the error im getting in line 8.

Comment: That's a good answer. Now i checked it again and no error. thank you.

Comment: sure I think. Take a look at `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` and `requests.Session()`

Comment: actually i'm new to this. but it seems interesting and i wanted to learn it. Can you be more specific. I'll greatful if you help me out.